# Can highslide pop up images be gif object with transparent background?

Tags: highslide

I was playing arround with [Highslide JS](http://highslide.com/) and was wondering if the image that pops out can be a transparent GIF or PNG without the white background/or with invisible backgroud.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, the image can be a GIF or PNG with transparency. A quick demo:

(demo removed)

Comment: So just want to point out to everyne what changes I did thanks to @EarlyOut help. So Here are the 3 things I changed to the code I got from Highslide editor I downloaded after setting up my settings on their site [highslide editor](http://highslide.com/editor/) : 1. In **highslide.config.js** I changed `hs.outlinetype='';` 2. In **highslide.css** I changed `.highslide-wrapper, .highslide-outline { background: none transparent scroll repeat 0% 0%; border-radius: 7px; }` and in `.highslide-image { background-color: transparent; cursor: pointer; border-radius: 7px; }` now it works!

Comment: Update: Hey just wanted to say that only 1 thing needs to be changed if your `hs.outlineType = null;` , and that is change the one at the bottom added by Highslide Editor: `.highslide-wrapper, .highslide-outline { background: transparent; }`